# PHP: Comparison within Assignment Statement

Tags: php, boolean, comparison, variable-assignment

In my never-ending quest to optimise my line usage, I've just got a quick question about what exactly can go into as assignment statement in PHP (and other languages too, but I'm working on a PHP project).

In my program I have a certain boolean variable, which is toggled by a few things summarised by an if statement. I thought, hang on, that if statement will evaluate to a boolean value, can I just use that logic in one line, as opposed to wrapping a separate assignment statement inside the if. Basically my question is will:

```
$myVar = ($a == $b);
```

be equivalent to

```
if ($a == $b) { $myVar = true; }
else { $myVar = false; }
```

As you can see, this saves me *one whole line*, so it will impact my project hugely. /sarcasm

Comment: You can take a look at the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). But don't make your code unreadable just by saving code lines.

Comment: I'd close this question, as ternary operator is a common knowledge. At the same time - I don't understand the huge impact of economy of lines of code. I'd also recommend you, Daniel, to read-up on PSR-2, it will definitely have huge impact on your PHP project ;) http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: Yeah, I was asking more out of curiosity than anything. Obviously an actual if statement makes it a bit more readable. I wasn't aware of the ternary operator. I did a bunch of googling for "Comparison inside assignment" and the like, but knowing that keyword would have helped.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a terinary operation. Something simialar to

```
$var = ($a === $b ? true : false);
echo $var;
```

Depending on the evaluation result of `$a === $b` the value of $var is then set.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, `$myVar = ($a == $b);` is the same as `if ($a == $b) { $myVar = true; } else { $myVar = false; }`.

And if you want to be even shorter, you can even remove the `(...)` and have it barely `$myVar = $a == $b;`